# Swift - Array to TableView in macOS

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview

I have some data form a JSON file which I have converted into:

```
var tempArray = [NSDictionary]()
```

Here is what a sample of this data looks like:

```
(
    {
        active = y;
        "campaign_id" = "Sample ID 1";
        description = "Sample Text";
        "end_date_time" = "2017-10-01 00:00:00";
        "on_expiry" = ignore;
        "on_invalid_user" = reject;
        "start_date_time" = "2017-07-01 00:00:00";
        "voucher_code" = SAMPLEON1;
        "voucher_code_id" = "Sample ID 4";
    },
    {
        active = y;
        "campaign_id" = "Sample ID 2";
        description = "Sample Text";
        "end_date_time" = "2017-10-01 00:00:00";
        "on_expiry" = ignore;
        "on_invalid_user" = reject;
        "start_date_time" = "2017-06-02 00:00:00";
        "voucher_code" = SAMPLEOFF1;
        "voucher_code_id" = "Sample ID 5";
    }
)
```

I have a NSTableView outlet set up, and it has columns with identifiers relative to the dictionary above:

```
@IBOutlet var voucherTableView: NSTableView!
```

Once I run the `voucherTableView.reloadData();` code in my Controller the table populates with the right amount of rows, but the data in the columns is all the same:

[image: After reloadData]

Here is my `tableView` func:

```
private func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {



        let cellView = voucherTableView.make(withIdentifier: "cell", owner: self) as! NSTableCellView

        cellView.textField!.stringValue = self.values.object(at: row) as! String

        return cellView
    }
```

Does anyone have any insight into how to get the data from my Array into the tableView on the reload command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use Cocoa Bindings

- Connect `datasource` of the table view in Interface Builder to the target class
- Implement these two methods (`viewForColumn:row` is not needed)

  ```
  func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int
  {
      return tempArray.count
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any?
  {
     return tempArray[row]
  }
  ```
- In Interface Builder Bindings Inspector bind the `value` of the text field to `Table Cell View > objectValue.[property]` for example

  [image]

Note: It's highly recommended to map the dictionaries to a custom class (a `class` inherited from `NSObject` is mandatory)

Comment: Excellent instruction! Worked like a charm, and I will look into mapping the dictionary to a custom class. This is all learning as I go really. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the column identifiers to match the keys in your dictionary, you should be able to do this:

```
private func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
    let cellView = voucherTableView.make(withIdentifier: "cell", owner: self) as! NSTableCellView

    cellView.textField!.stringValue = tempArray[row][tableColumn.identifier] as! String

    return cellView
}
```